# React-Virtualized: Infinitely scrolling list

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm encountering an issue while building an infinitely scrolling list. I need to maintain the scroll position but render more rows at the bottom. `react-virtualized` provides `scrollTo` but this doesn't seem enough since we do not have the current scrolledTo index. Calculating the `scrollTo` index dynamically using `clientHeight`, `scrollHeight` and `scrollTop` can only provide an approximation especially when the rows are of dynamic height.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to maintain the scroll position but render more rows at the bottom.

Adding more rows to the end/bottom will not affect scroll position.

> react-virtualized provides scrollTo but this doesn't seem enough since we do not have the current scrolledTo index.

You pass the scroll-to prop to react-virtualized so you must have it. You can use the `onScroll` or `onRowsRendered` callback if you want to be notified of user-initiated scroll changes though.

Comment: I'm using `onScroll` to capture the event but it seems impossible to add rows to the bottom, remove rows from the top and retain the users view as is. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? react-virtualized does this for you automatically. Just tell it how many rows there are total- feel free to increase the count if you load additional data after the fact- and it will render only what's necessary to fill the viewport. Works like this https://bvaughn.github.io/forward-js-2017/#/12/4

Comment: I'm clearly not explaining my problem well. I have an activity feed which is constantly receiving new feed. The user can also scroll down to fetch old feed. Since this could be a cause for major memory consumption, we've capped the list at 200 activities in memory. This list is then passed on to react-virtualized. Upon fetching old feed, new items are remove from memory and vice-versa. The problem is that it seems very hard to maintain the exact scroll position when getting old feed. Come to think of it, a combination of `scrollToAlignment` and `scrollToIndex` may work.

Comment: You should be able to remove old feed items (eg throw away the JavaScript/JSON data that underlies them) without invalidating `List`'s position cache- in which case, it still should impact your scroll position. This just may be one of those questions that's too hard to answer without seeing code and a demo.

Comment: I totally understand. Creating a demo project or providing code will take some time. Appreciate your responses.

Comment: Feel free to hop in the Slack channel when you have something to show. May be easier to talk there. https://react-virtualized.now.sh/

Comment: A combination of `scrollToAlignment` and `scrollToIndex` did the trick. A couple caveats - I have to trigger fetching of old feed when the users scrolls to the very bottom but more importantly, the Macbook touchpad buffers scrolling and causes the list to scroll after more items are added. I overcome this by disabling the `wheel` event temporarily on the list.

Comment: Ah, yeah the momentum scrolling is tricky for things like what RV does. Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: I have got a similar issue. Can you please help me? Here is the link of question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58446144/2284240. I have included a codesandbox as well, which may be easier for you to find the cause of the issue.